# using get und set method to change format of a string - set method never gets called

Tags: angular, typescript

I get a datetime via http and want to format it before I use it. For that I use the get and set method, but the set method never gets called.

My component (AdminComponent):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AdminService } from './admin.service';
import { Config } from './_config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {


    config: Config = new Config();

    constructor(private adminService: AdminService) { }

    ngOnInit() {

      this.getConfig();
    }


    getConfig(): void { //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART FOR THIS QUESTION
        this.adminService.getConfig().subscribe(config => {
            this.config = config;
            console.log(this.config); //just to debug
        });
    }
    saveConfig(): void {
        //here will come the save
    }

}
```

the AdminService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Config } from './_config';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminService {

    private getConfigUrl = '//../getConfig.php';
    private saveConfigUrl = '//../saveConfig.php';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.getConfigUrl = window.location.protocol+this.getConfigUrl;
      this.saveConfigUrl = window.location.protocol+this.saveConfigUrl;
  }


    getConfig(): Observable<Config> {
        var data = ""; //is used but not necessary for this example.
        var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
        return this.http.post<Config>(this.getConfigUrl, data, { headers: headers } ).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('admin getConfig', [])));
    }

    saveConfig(config: Config) {
        var data = "config="+JSON.stringify(config);
        var headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
        return this.http.post<string>(this.saveConfigUrl, data, { headers: headers } ).pipe(catchError(this.handleError('admin saveConfig', [])));
    }





          /**
   * Handle Http operation that failed.
   * Let the app continue.
   * @param operation - name of the operation that failed
   * @param result - optional value to return as the observable result
   */
  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
      console.error(error); // log to console instead

      // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```

And the Config class (where I use the get and set method):

```
export class Config {
    title: string;
    _startdate: Date;
    enddate: Date;

    public get startdate(): string {
        console.log("get called");
        return this.parseDateToStringWithFormat(this._startdate);
    }

    public set startdate(v: string) {
        console.log("set called");
        let actualParsedDate = v ? new Date(v) : new Date();
        let normalizedParsedDate = new Date(actualParsedDate.getTime() + (actualParsedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
        console.log("from: "+v+" to: "+normalizedParsedDate);
        this._startdate = normalizedParsedDate;
    }


    private parseDateToStringWithFormat(date: Date): string {
        //formats the date-string to be usable in the input type="datetime-local"
        return date.toISOString().substring(0,16);
    }
}
```

I changed the name of `startdate` to `_startdate` and created a get and set method for `startdate`. In my template I use doublebinding to a input field like : `<input type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="config.startdate">`

Looking at my console, the set method is never called, but the get method is called. When the get is called `this._startdate` is undefined. So I guess I do something fundamentally wrong.

My goal is to not have to handle the date-formation in the component and I would like to do it directly in the Config class.

**Edit:** if I change the function `getConfig()` from the AdminService to set every variable separately it works, see here:

```
getConfig(): void {
        this.adminService.getConfig().subscribe(config => {
            this.config.title = config.title;
            this.config.startdate = config.startdate;
            this.config.enddate = config.enddate;
            console.log(this.config);
        });
    }
```

As Config has only 3 variables this is not a big deal, however in bigger Classes this is not really what I looking for. Also I am not sure why the first version does not work?

Comment: Hi, i think your problem is that you are calling the method after the `subscribe` on the `getConfig`.
Am I right?

Comment: what is the console output?  "get called"?

Comment: by the way, I think `new Date().toISOString()` does what _parseDateToStringWithFormat_ is doing

Comment: @Gaspar yes "get called" is the console output, but never "set called". Also you are right with the toISOString() method. More exactly, it would be: `.toISOString().substring(0,16)` - I will edit that in my question to make the code smaller, but it doesn't effect the problem at all.

Comment: @AlbertoAM tbh see my edit at the end of the question

Comment: yes because you are doing it inside a `subscribe` so it's been doing sequentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why now, you are not setting anything to it... SET will be called when your code set values in

```
getConfig(): void { //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART FOR THIS QUESTION
    this.adminService.getConfig().subscribe(config => {
        this.config = config; // this is where you are calling GET                
        config.startdate = 'foo'; // this is a SET example
        console.log(this.config);
    });
}
```

EDIT:
If your code get too big you can use a *constructor* in Config class:

```
class Config {

    private title: string;
    private startdate: string;
    private enddate: string;

    constructor(title: string, startdate: string, enddate: string) {
        this.title = title;
        this.startdate = startdate;
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    // ... getters/setters
}
```

I think this is the best way to use classes in typescript

Comment: Thanks, I found out the same (see the edit at the end of the question). In this example Config only has 3 variables so it's not a big deal. But other classes could have 100s of variables. I hoped, as I use the Config class in the Service and the http request that this will works automatically. Is there a more generic solution?

Comment: thanks! I think using the constructor will do the trick! I will check this and accept your answer if it works. Not even thought about using the constructor..

Comment: I analysed it closer and found out that when I do `this.config = config; ` the prototype of `this.config` changes -> the getter and setter don't work anymore, etc. So will keep set every variable separately to not overwrite the prototype.